# File in Trash unable to be deleted

Tags: macos, trash

OSX El Capitan won't let me delete a file in my Trash. I've tried everything -- the secret keyboard shortcut, going to `~/.Trash` in Terminal and doing an `rm -rf`, etc. Here's a Bash session that shows this:

```
~ $ cd ~/.Trash

~/.Trash $ ls
site

~/.Trash $ sudo rm -rf site
rm: site/static/main.styl: Operation not permitted
rm: site/static: Directory not empty
rm: site: Directory not empty

~/.Trash $ cd site/static

~/.Trash/site/static $ sudo rm -rf main.styl 
rm: main.styl: Operation not permitted

~/.Trash/site/static $ ls -lh main.styl
-r--r--r--  1 bh  staff   595B 26 Jul 14:16 main.styl
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening, or how I might fix this?

Comment: I think [this question on Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/101328) can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a tiny app called 'Trash It!': http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/8214/trash-it!

Also CleanMyMac 3.1.1 can be a solution.